# brew couldn't upgrade after upgrade xcode 7.3.1 to 8.1

Tags: xcode, upgrade, homebrew

I upgraded xcode from 7.3.1 to 8.1 and also I update homebrew using [brew update]. after that I could use [brew upgrade]. It shown the following warning message

Warning: You are using a pre-release version of Xcode.
   You may encounter build failures or other breakages.
   Please create pull-requests instead of filing issues.

I used [brew config] and it shown the following info

```
  HOMEBREW_VERSION: 1.0.8-54-g8019afb
  ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew.git
  HEAD: 8019afb60ad321b0f14f60b00c23d7fb098d35c2
  Last commit: 6 days ago
  Core tap ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core
  Core tap HEAD: 83f73d73fac8229ac523bf839b8a5913de05bf08
  Core tap last commit: 3 hours ago
  HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
  HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY: /usr/local/Homebrew
  HOMEBREW_CELLAR: /usr/local/Cellar
  HOMEBREW_BOTTLE_DOMAIN: https://homebrew.bintray.com
  CPU: quad-core 64-bit haswell
  Homebrew Ruby: 2.0.0-p648
  Clang: 8.0 build 800
  Git: 2.9.3 => /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/git
  Perl: /usr/bin/perl
  Python: /usr/bin/python
  Ruby: /usr/local/bin/ruby => /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1_2/bin/ruby
  Java: 1.8.0_25
  macOS: 10.11.6-x86_64
  Xcode: 8.1
  CLT: 7.3.1.0.1.1461711523
```

I think the last line of above info [CLT] means command line tools and its version is 7.3.1..., I think it should be 8.1 because Xcode is 8.1. How can I upgrade CLT from 7.3.1 to 8.1?

Comment: did you try to re-run `xcode-select --install` already? Also: an upgrade/update should be available in App Store - you may have to start the new xcode once. As last resort you can download clt 8.1 from developer.apple.com.

Comment: Not succeed trying resolve this problem. I'd try `rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools` and run `xcode-select --install` again, it still install the CLT 7.3, even then system upgrade told me I have an update of "Xcode Command Lines Tools 7.3", interesting

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue:

- `brew` is not up-to-date even though running `brew update` returns:

  > Already up-to-date
- Running `brew upgrade` returns:

  > Warning: You are using a pre-release version of Xcode.
  > You may encounter build failures or other breakages.
  > Please create pull-requests instead of filing issues.

I solved running the following command:

```
cd "$(brew --repo)" && git fetch && git reset --hard origin/master && brew update --force
```

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading Xcode you need to point the command line tools to the new version of Xcode. If you did an AppStore upgrade the command line tools shouldn't change. Try running this command:

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app
```

to set up the tools again.

I install Xcode from the xip files and rename it with the version number (i.e. Xcode833.app)

So to point the command line tools to the new tools I use the command:

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode833.app
```

Running that command will require you to enter your admin password.